# Drop rows with at least a cell having a value in a given list with the .isin pandas.DataFrame method

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use the `.isin` method but I don't have the expected result.

Here is a minimal reproducible example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4], 'num_wings': [2, 0]}, index=['falcon', 'dog'])
print(df)
print(df[df.isin([0, 2])])
```

It doesn't delete the row, but replaces the cell by NaN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For filtering need bolean Series, if check all column get boolean DataFrame:

So if need test if at least one True per row use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), If need test if all  True per row use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (df.isin([0, 2]))
        num_legs  num_wings
falcon      True       True
dog        False       True

print (df.isin([0, 2]).any(axis=1))
falcon    True
dog       True
dtype: bool

print (df.isin([0, 2]).all(axis=1))
falcon     True
dog       False
dtype: bool

print(df[df.isin([0, 2]).any(axis=1)])
        num_legs  num_wings
falcon         2          2
dog            4          0

print(df[df.isin([0, 2]).all(axis=1)])
        num_legs  num_wings
falcon         2          2
```

Comment: Thanks!!
If I want to get this new dataframe without the values and ALSO a dataframe with the values dropped, doing `df = df[df.isin(list_ref).all(axis=1)]` then `df2 = df[~df.isin(list_ref).all(axis=1)]` might be not optimal computationnally speaking. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `m = df.isin(list_ref).all(axis=1)` and then `df1 = df[m]` and `df2 = df[~m]`